# XSLT Help getting Distinct values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document (shown below), what I need to do is get a list of all the unique Type @ID values, regardless of where they are below SizeRanges

So for this document I need to get 10,8,6,5 into something I can use for-each upon.

Ultimately, I'm trying to show each SizeRange in a table beside each other, and get the same Types to line up on the same row.  But the problem I am having is extracting a distinct list of Types I can loop on.

XML Document:

```
<SizeRanges>
    <SizeRange ID="1" Name="8-18">
        <Types>
            <Type ID="10">
                <Size Name="8"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="10" Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="12" Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="14" Quantity="3" />
                <Size Name="16" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="18" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="8">
                <Size Name="8"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="10" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="12" Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="14" Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="16" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="18" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="6">
                <Size Name="8"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="10" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="12" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="14" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="16" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="18" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="5">
                <Size Name="10" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="12" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="14" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="16" Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="18" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
        </Types>
    </SizeRange>
    <SizeRange ID="2" Name="S-XL">
        <Types>
            <Type ID="10">
                <Size Name="S"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="M"  Quantity="3" />
                <Size Name="L"  Quantity="4" />
                <Size Name="XL" Quantity="2" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="8">
                <Size Name="S"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="M"  Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="L"  Quantity="3" />
                <Size Name="XL" Quantity="2" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="6">
                <Size Name="S"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="M"  Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="L"  Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="XL" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
            <Type ID="5">
                <Size Name="S"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="M"  Quantity="1" />
                <Size Name="L"  Quantity="2" />
                <Size Name="XL" Quantity="1" />
            </Type>
        </Types>
    </SizeRange>
</SizeRanges>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
<xsl:key name="types" match="Type" use="@ID"/>
<xsl:variable name="distinctTypes" as="xs:integer*" select="distinct-values(//SizeRange/Types/Type)" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$distinctTypes">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's another way:

```
<xsl:key name="types" match="Type" use="@ID"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//SizeRange/Types/Type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', @ID)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: small correction for the line. `match="type"` here **type**, **T** should be caps then it works fine.. 
`<xsl:key name="types" match="Type" use="@ID"/>`

Comment: @Siva Charan: Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I can't use distinct-values as I don't have XSLT 2 but the second way worked great.

Answer (score 1):

on XSLT 2.0, you can do this way..

```
distinct-values(/SizeRanges/SizeRange/Types/Type/@ID)
```

This gives unique ID's as output